# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Mac using Bootcamp?

Tags: system-installation, mac

I want a native Ubuntu installation, not an VM.  Do I have options on my Mac (that don't involve destroying the 'Mac' portion of it) or should I just switch to a standard PC?  If I do have options, it would be nice to know what they are :-p

Comment: Is your Mac running on an Intel chip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have options! There are help pages for installing on Macs that show the hardware support and installation alongside OSX.

Here is the page where you select which hardware you have:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages

Just click through, select the version of Ubuntu and you'll get some installation instructions. Be sure to check the hardware compatibility too because you might not want to install if certain things aren't going to work.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: is it possible to install and boot to Ubuntu using Bootcamp?

Comment: Note that for e.g. MacBookPro, the latest supported version is 11,3 which is from back in 2013-2014. Later versions seem to be unsupported.

Answer (score 5):

No, Bootcamp only supports ISO files for Windows 10 or later.  This was tested on MacOS Catalina 10.15 Beta.

[Popup that appears if you try to attach an Ubuntu ISO file in Bootcamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5rep.jpg)

[This link](https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733) outlines a way to install Ubuntu as a dual-boot system on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

The instructions for non-destructive, dual boot Mac/Ubuntu setup can be found [on Ubuntu Community pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Dual-Boot%3a%20Mac%20OSX%20and%20Ubuntu). I've have followed that instruction and installed Ubuntu 11.04 on MacBook Pro side by side with OSX. Both systems work fine.

Comment: what's your macbook model? I've tried several times to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my mbpro'11 and failed all time: installed OK but after installing kernel and other updates - it doesn't start, empty screen after grub2 menu...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to install Ubuntu on Macs (without destroying OS X) using Bootcamp. Bootcamp is made for Mac users to install Windows alongside OS X.

Answer (score 0):

easier way after burning the ubuntu cd restart your mac when the white screen comes up press quickly alt the you should insert the ubuntu cd dont go into efi but go to windows 
then you can install it . before all of this be careful dont partiton you hard disk

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bootcamp: too dodgy use disk utility to partition as ExFat; ready to accept Ubuntu 22.04/23.04 installation via a flash drive installer, ideally created with Rufus on a Windows10/11 machine