# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 10.10 and/or Ubuntu 11.04 on a late 2009 iMac?

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, installation, updates, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Mac using Bootcamp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1832/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-mac-using-bootcamp)

I would like to install Ubuntu on my iMac 10,1 (21.5 inch display). I would prefer to instal Natty Narwhal, but would surely settle for Maverick Meerkat (which I have a install dvd of).

I have an install of OS X Snow Leopard AND a Bootcamp Partition of Windows 7. I would like to keep all these partitions and setup a triple boot system.

If it can work, I'm also wondering if it'd be safe to install all updates from the update manager once it's installed.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1832/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-mac-using-bootcamp

Answer (score 0):

I really do not have any experience with iMacs, but I would suspect that either 10.10 or 11.04 would install.  This is based on my experiences with older PCs and my ability to run either flavor of Ubuntu on them.  However, please ensure you have the appropriate install disc.