# I erased osx when i installed ubuntu, how do i set up dual boot

Tags: installation, dual-boot, macbook, mac

I have a macbook pro 8,1 running ubuntu 11.10 on it.  Before I wiped osx clean off it, i was running osx lion.

This computer was shipped with snow leopard on it so i know it will work on it, but when i try to run the install disk (Even before ubuntu while on lion) i got all kinds of kernel panic and it told me to restart my computer.

i just want a dual boot set up so how do i make a partition in ubuntu and put mac on it?

Comment: I changed your question to say '..how do I set up dual boot' from 'how do I get it back'. We all know you can't "get it back" once you clear the disk

Comment: Okay... but why?  And thats fine, i just want to be able to boot back and forth between linux and mac. but as of now mac no longer exists on here

Comment: If you haven't found the answer by now, I would suggest just installing Snow Leopard and let the install wipe out your Ubuntu.  Then follow the usual instructions to install Ubuntu alongside OS X.

Answer (score 4):

As Chan-Ho Suh mentioned in the comments

> If you haven't found the answer by now, I would suggest just installing Snow Leopard and let the install wipe out your Ubuntu. Then follow the usual instructions to install Ubuntu alongside OS X.

This is your best bet to fix your macbook pro 8

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1832/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-mac-using-bootcamp). A similar question that already has answers. Let me know if this doesn't help you.

Comment: There are a lot of pages about installing Ubuntu alongside an already existing OS X installation...I think this is the first time I've seen someone asking how to install OS X on an Ubuntu MacBook Pro!  This might actually be quite tricky...the Ubuntu installer expects there to be other OSes, I suspect the OS X installer will complain.